# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] & Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-services

I am using AngularJS 1.3.5 and I am trying to get an information from a json file.
Here is my code:
The HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/myapp.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="MainController">

            
                <div ng-repeat="content in contents">
   

<a ng-href="{{data.FolderPath}}">{{data.FolderPath}}</a>
                
     
                    
                </div>
            
       
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript files:
MainController.js

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'myapp', function($scope, myapp) {
  myapp.success(function(data) {
    $scope.FolderPath = data;
  });
}]);
```

myapp.js

```js
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('C:\Users\nouri\Desktop\configFile.json') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

and finally app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('FolderApp', []);
```

I corrected the errors hwoever now I am having a white screen so my code didn't read what is in my json file:
    {
      "FolderPath": "C:\Users\nouri\Desktop\test" 
    }
what should I do[image]

Comment: You can't return from asynchronous function. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be 2 issues with your code

1. Order in which you are loading the scripts. Load app.js followed by services/myapp.js and then controllers/MainController.js.

   ```html
       <script src="js/app.js"></script>
       <script src="js/services/myapp.js"></script>
       <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
   ```
2. The name of your angular module is FolderApp but you have referenced it as 'app'. Change it as

   ```html
       <body ng-app="FolderApp">
   ```

**EDIT**
There is an issue with the way you are using your factory. You should return an object containing a method that will call the API and return back the $http promise. Try something like this:
**Factory**

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) { 
   return {
    getJson: function() {
       return $http.get('C:\Users\nouri\Desktop\configFile.json');
    }
  }
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'myapp', function($scope, factory) {
  factory.callApi()
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.FolderPath = data;
    });
}]);
```

Take a look at this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2807/).

Comment: Thank you it helped me, now I have another problem . I edited my question with the error I had

Comment: There is a problem with your factory implementation as well. Check my Edit.

Comment: Thank you but I still be unable to read my json file . check my question edit please

Comment: What is the format of your json file? And can you check from the network tab if the file is getting properly loaded by the $http call?

Comment: it's a json file not a txt or any other type file

Answer (score 1):

The order of the files matter... place your `app.js` at the top and also your `app-name` defined in your html should match the `js` too.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` before the other files (but after the angular core)

Answer (score 1):

in the html you defined

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

But in the js you are using:

```
var app = angular.module('FolderApp', []);
```

Change one of the 2 and place

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

on top and you should be ok

Comment: Thank you I still have this error ..
angular.js:11500Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/ng/areq?p0=MainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Ob (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:19:393)
    at pb (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:19:480)

Comment: at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:75:274
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:57:112
    at r (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at H (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:56:496)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:51:299)

Comment: at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:51:316)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11500(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8479k.$apply @ angular.js:14391(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1437e @ angular.js:4138d @ angular.js:1435rc @ angular.js:1455Gd @ angular.js:1349(anonymous function) @ angular.js:25912a @ angular.js:2722c @ angular.js:2992

Comment: edit the question and put the console log I can't read it from here sry

Comment: here you can see a simplified version of your app https://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/r3guc8k6/

Comment: In the fiddle you have a CORS problem caused by the static file on your hd. You have to serve stati resource with a local web server to avoid those kind of problems douring development.

Answer (score 1):

change ng-app="app" to ng-app="FolderApp"

Comment: Thank you now I don't have any error However , nothing is showed from my json file I have a white screen

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, in fact and for security reasons, AngularJS can't read local json files . It only reads online ones. Thanks for those who helped me ^^